# How do I make a gameobject's rotation follow that of another's

Tags: unity-game-engine

in unity, I am trying to make a "bullet" spawn in the direction my player rotates, but I am unsure how

I tried this code, but it did not work (and I am seeing why)
transform.Translate(Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);
this just spawns it infront of my other gameobject

Comment: well usually you would use transform.forward * distance you want in front... but hey you did google that right?

Answer (score 0):

to spawn the bullet in front of the player you can use:

bullet.transform.position = player.transform.position + player.trasform.forward * d

where d is the distance you want between the player and the bullet. you can then add the code to make the bullet fly